# Stirling number series resummation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, stirling-numbers, polylogarithm

\begin{equation}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_1^3 S_m^{(3)} (u-1)^{m-1}
 \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^m}{m!}\end{equation}
Does somebody know the result of this resummation?

Note:
$S_m^{(3)} $ belongs to the Stirling number of the first kind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind
If you see the wiki page "Table of values" $S_m^{(3)} $ corresponds to the third column.

Please let me know if addition information is needed.

Comment: to be clear, you want to formally express that sum in simpler terms? If yes, I would starts by doing $z=(u-1)x/(x-1)$ and using that ${m\brack 3}=(m-1)!\left (H_{m-1}^2-H_{m-1,2}\right ).$ Notice that the generating function for generalized harmonic numbers involves the polylogarithmi functions.

Comment: @Phicar yes, the answer is some logs or polylogs.

Comment: @Phicar I figured this out. Thank you!

Comment: Cool, you want to post a solution? You can accept your own solution. If not, I can provide one too.

Comment: @Phicar Thank you for your interest. You can provide yours.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. You can provide yours. And I wouldn't upload one.

Comment: @Phicar Here is a further question. Would you also answer this ?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951223/further-stirling-number-series-resummation
Thank you.